# How to associate specific files (NOT file types) with syntax highlighting in Sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have build_config (and other *_config files), GdbRun and build.txt files which are basically bash shell scripts.
How could I associate these files with shell syntax ? To place a pattern like
'if filename is *_config or GdbRun or build.txt' somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BufferScroll](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BufferScroll) plugin can remember most of view settings for a particular file including syntax.

Just install BufferScroll and change the syntax manually using the status bar or the command palette and it'll remember it next time you open that file.

Comment: Good, it keeps syntax selection for my files.